# Django / UploadFileForm only provides No valid form?

Tags: python, django

i try to create a simple file-upload funcionality with Django using the following code / files -

Its more or less taken from this example:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/http/file-uploads/

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    file = forms.FileField()
```

views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import UploadFileForm
import os
import sys

def handle_uploaded_file(f):
    path = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]))     
    fnFile = os.path.join(path, "gpp", "FILES", "QUESTIONS", "someFile.xyz")    
    print(fnFile)
    with open(fnFile, 'wb+') as destination:
        for chunk in f.chunks():
            destination.write(chunk)

def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        print(request.POST)
        print(request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            print(f"Valid form")
            handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file'])
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/success/url/')
        else:
            print("No valid form")
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'form': form})
```

Generally the form looks fine and i can choose the file:

[image]

But when i enter something it doesn´t work seeing the following in the log:

```
[23/Mar/2024 10:02:35] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1777
<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['HWaddf1sBsKJc1k4CY9LiijIv1VAlxjWkRoFRixEP12rNDYyIx6zRYFC2MvPKIFm'], 'title': ['Test'], 'file': ['gpt.zip'], 'save': ['']}>
<MultiValueDict: {}>
No valid form
[23/Mar/2024 10:04:33] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 1869
```

So it seems that request.FILES is for whatever reason empty?
Why is this not working as intended?

Comment: Can you share the HTML?

Comment: does your html include `enctype="multipart/form-data"`?
so like `<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Comment: per the documentation: `Note that request.FILES will only contain data if the request method was POST, at least one file field was actually posted, and the <form> that posted the request has the attribute enctype="multipart/form-data". Otherwise, request.FILES will be empty.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to set the [**`enctype="…"`** <sup>[mdn-doc]</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/enctype) of the form to allow both data and file uploads:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form }}
</form>
```